# ASP.NET Pagination

Tags: c#

Goodday!

For the first time I am busy with ASP.NET to create a website. Over here I have some RESTfulAPI GETS in a List. But I would like to have this in pieces. Like show me the first 10 records, after a page refresh show me the next. And if this is the last page go back to the first page.

On the internet there is a lot of stuff, but everyone tells me something else.

I have this code below to set a value how many records the page will show. But whatever I try, I will see everything or nothing. theirafter I need to figure out how it will be possible to refresh the url and show me the next 10 records.

My code;

```
public class Person
 {
  public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
  public string MiddleName { get; set; } = "";
  public string FrstName { get; set; }
 }


public void Pagin_Persons()
 {
  int pagesize = 10;
  int countitems = Persons.Count(); // Does have 17 records
  int pagecount = countitems % pagesize <= 0 ? countitems / pagesize : (countitems / pagesize) + 1;
  for (int page = 0; page < pagecount; page++)
   {
    Persons = Persons.Skip(page * pagesize).Take(pagesize).ToList();
   }
  }
```